# nginx redirect when port is not mtached and uri is matched

Tags: nginx, redirect, config

How can I configure nginx as reverse proxy that if client request came to nginx server port is not (!=) 443 AND client request begins from /ui/ path redirect will be worke to https://$server_name$request_uri (port 443)?

Fo example my application have two endpoins - api and ui.
nginx server listening port 443 and port 8080
I want that if requests come to https://example.com/ui/ or https://example.com/api/ or http://example.com:8080/api/ everything remained unchanged  but if requests come to http://example.com:8080/ui/ they will be redirect to  https://example.com/ui/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using simple HTTPS with the default port (which it seems like), you can just create a host, that redirects everything as follows:

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server; # you need to specify all ports, you want to redirect separately
    server_name _; # match any hostname
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri; # redirect to https (port 443) and append the request URI
}
```